# find out the keyboard shortcuts of a window programmatically

Tags: windows, winapi, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

is there a way to find out what keys is a window listening for (preferably Windows)?

or at least the menu Alt-keys?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it. Each function participating in the window message handling can choose to ignore the message or to execute some code.